# How to specify Libs variable of pkgconfig during its generation by qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake, pkg-config

I want to set `Libs:` line via qmake **.pro** file and I try doing it like this:

```
LIBS += -ldl
```

to make my target executable be also linked with `dl` library because my library I am trying to link it with uses `dl` inside. However, this does not work, and `qmake` puts this string into `Libs.private` section instead which is not passed to `gcc` command line during compilation and so I am unable to produce an executable:

```
Libs.private: -ldl
```

while I want it to be in `Libs:` line like that:

```
Libs: -lmylibrary -ldl
```

I also can't find any references to `QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_*` variables anywhere in the web, is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Is used for generating .pc files:

```
CONFIG += create_pc create_prl no_install_prl
```

By greping for `QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_` I found the following in `~/5.12.0/clang_64/mkspecs/features/qt_module.prf`

```
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_DESTDIR
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_INCDIR
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_CFLAGS
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_NAME
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_FILE
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_DESCRIPTION
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_INSTALL_REPLACE
```

From the man page for pkg-config:

```
Libs.private:
  This line should list any private libraries in use.  
  Private libraries are libraries which are not exposed  through  your library, 
  but are needed in the case of static linking. 
  This differs from Requires.private in that it references 
  libraries that do not have package files installed.
```

So i guess as long as you don't export them through your lib they will end up in Libs.private.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt but this does not answer the question.